# split git repo with nested subdirectory structure

Tags: git

After much searching, I haven't found anything specific to splitting a git repo that contains nested subdirectories, such as for java packages. I want to take one nested subdir for a package and move to it's own repo. For example, starting with:

|root1 
|--com 
|----mycompany 
|-------foo 
|-------bar 
where foo and bar contain different packages conforming to java's package-directory rules; there are no files in the com and mycompany directories.

I want to move foo to it's own repo, leaving com/mycompany/bar intact; the new repo should contain com/mycompany/foo, thus:

|newroot2 
|--com 
|----mycompany 
|-------foo 
and leave root1 with everything except foo

|root1 
|--com 
|----mycompany 
|-------bar

Simple as this sounds, almost every blog, SO question and example show only a one deep directory split, with the subdirectory becoming the root of the new repo. Not what I want.

Ideally, the commit history for each package would be preserved, but separated into the respective repos.

I tried:  git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r com/mycompany/bar' -- --all to remove the bar stuff, which appeared to remove bar from git tracking, but with no apparent effect on the history.
Also tried:git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter com/mycompany/foo HEAD  -- --all but that put all the foo files in the repo root.

Many people have asked similar questions, but I've yet to find anything that addresses preserving the root and nested (java) subdirectory structure.

Can anyone describe how to split the packages, keeping history per package, into separate repos?